# Proof that for $e>3$, the number of quadratic residues $a$, s.t. $gcd(a,2^e)$ and $0<a<n $ is $2^{e-3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm just wondering if someone can help with the 2nd part of the proof to understand this proposition leading to the conclusion.

I understand that for $2^e, e>3$, $a$ is a quadratic residue, if and only if $a\equiv 1 (mod \space 8)$.

I understand the "if" part of the proof, since if $2^e | x^2 -a$ then $2^3 | x^2 -a$ must also hold.

but I am having trouble understanding the "only if" part, in particular how we can show that the set of quadratic residues mod $2^e$ is equal to the number of $a_i$, s.t.

$$a_i\equiv 1 (mod \space 8)$$ with  $ gcd(a,2^e)=1 $ and $0<a<2^e$

and that this = $2^{e-3}$

I haven't studied group theory yet, only elementary number theory, so if there is a proof that uses mainly elementary number theory ideas, that would be most helpful.

Many sincere thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that if $a$ is a square $\pmod{2^{e+1}}$, then $a+2^e$ is a square too, since $a\equiv b^2\pmod{2^{e+1}}$ implies $a+2^e \equiv (b+c\,2^{e-1})^2\pmod{2^{e+1}}$, where $c$ can be chosen in order to have $bc\equiv 1\pmod{2^{e+1}}$. Moreover, in order to have that $a$ is a square $\pmod{2^{e+1}}$, $a$ must be a square $\pmod{2^e}$, so, starting with $e=3$, the claim can be proved by induction on $e$.

Comment: Hi Jack, sorry I am having a bit of trouble following your answer. Could you clarify how you went from $a\equiv b^2 \pmod{2^{e+1}}$ to $a+2^e \equiv (b+c\,2^{e-1})^2\pmod{2^{e+1}}$?, If I add $2^e$ to both sides of the 1st congruence I get  $a + 2^e \equiv b^2 + 2^{e-1} \cdot 2 \pmod{2^{e+1}}$, I also don't really understand the $c$ you have chosen? Could you clarify a bit more? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Assume that $a$ is coprime with $2^{e+1}$ and it is a square $\pmod{2^{e+1}}$: then it is the square of something, say $b$. Now take $c$ as the inverse of $b$ (an integer such that $bc\equiv 1\pmod{2^{e+1}}$ - it must exist since you are considering integers such that $\gcd(a,2^{e+1})=1$, i.e. odd numbers), and compute the square of $b+c 2^{e-1}$: what you get is $b^2+ 2^e bc + c^2 2^{2e-2}$, that is congruent to $a+2^e\pmod{2^{e+1}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I do follow your answer and checked that it does indeed hold true for $e=3$. However, could you explain to me which way the induction should go? It's still not clear to me how this is proving the "and only if" part. It seems like we are starting with the assumption that a is a QR of mod $2^{e+1}$ and then showing that it is also a QR of mod $2^{e}$? Should we not be starting with the opposite assumption? Thanks again.

Comment: You're right, we have to prove that an odd QR $\pmod{2^e}$ is still a QR $\pmod{2^{e+1}}$. In fact, $a\equiv b^2\pmod{2^e}$ implies $a = b^2 + k 2^e$: if $k$ is even then $a$ is a QR $\pmod{2^{e+1}}$, otherwise, by taking $c$ as the inverse of $b\pmod{2^{e+1}}$, $(b+kc 2^{e-1})^2= b^2 + kbc 2^e + k^2c^2 2^{2e-2} \equiv a\pmod{2^{e+1}}$, so $a$ is an odd QR $\pmod{2^{e+1}}$ anyway. This technique is also known as Hensel lifting.

Comment: Can I just clarify as well, I don't immediately see why it's always possible to find a $c$ s.t. $bc \equiv 1 \pmod {2^{e+1}}$. You mentioned that this is due to the fact that we are considering only $a$ s.t. $gcd(a,2^{e+1}) = 1$, but from my textbooks this just means we can always find an inverse to $a$, why is it that we can find an inverse to $b$? What am I missing here?

Comment: If $a=b^2$ and $a$ is odd, $b$ is odd, too, so $\gcd(b,2^{e+1})=1$ and you can find an inverse of $b$.